# How to take characters in a text file as arguments

Tags: c++, file, text, input, command

I'm fairly new to C++, I'm trying to figure out how to take in arguments from a text file and use them in my program.

So if I wanted to include a text file whatever.txt in a command, it would use specified lines as arguments.

Like if the text file looked like this:

1 2

and I wanted to use 1 and 2 from it, as arguments in my program.

So far from what I've gathered, I need something akin to this:

```
int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
```

to start, but not sure where to go from here.

I'm trying to mess around with certain stuff, but I'm still pretty new and outside of loops and things I can't do much with the language yet!

Answer (score 1):

Short of giving you the code that will do this for you (which would ruin the fun of learning how to do these things), the steps I would follow would be:

1. Take one argument from the command line as the file name you want to read the information from. Think of running your script like this:
   `$ ./myscript whatever.txt`
   Then, `argv[0]="./myscript"` and `argv[1]="whatever.txt"`.
2. Open the file (perhaps `ifstream` would be good for this).
3. Loop through each line of the file (maybe using `getline` to put each line into a string)
4. Parse each line of the file (I've seen `stringstream` used for filling variables from a string).

Hopefully that will help you along your way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

after retrieving files names in the main function you should open each file and retrieve its contents

Sample code

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        for(int i=1; i <= argc; i++) // i=1, assuming files arguments are right after the executable
           {
               string fn = argv[i]; //filename
               cout << fn; 
               fstream f;
               f.open(fn);
               //your logic here
               f.close();
           }
     return 0;
     }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30141375/3323444

Answer (score 0):

argc is the number of arguments passed in to your program, argv is an array of character strings holding the names of arguments passed in.

at least there's one parameter passed in which is argv[0] which is name of program.

after building this code run it form a command prompt as:

```
main.exe data.txt
```

or simply DRAG AND DROP file "data.txt" on your main.exe

main.exe is your program, data.txt is text file containing data you want to use

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    char c;

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "No file passed to program!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::ifstream in (argv[1] , std::ios::in);
    if(!in)
        std::cout << "Unable to read file: " << argv[1] << std::endl;

    while(in >> c)
        std::cout << c << std::endl;

    in.close();


    std::cin.get();
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Minor nag: `argv[0]` doesn't have to be the program name. Most often it is the command used to execute the program. This may or may not include path and it may or may not have been aliased to the point where using it to find the program name is an exercise in futility. Also, in order to throw a bone to really lightweight systems, `argv[0]` can be left blank although I believe the standard requires it to be there. You'll probably only ever see this on an embedded system.

Comment: @user4581301 I know but I just explained. you can do: `argv[0] = "Hello";` then `return main(argc, argv);` then `argv[0]` is string hello.